# I can't understand why the log shows the array items, but the array itself is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, class, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project implementing a class using typescript, but I stumbled across this problem that I can't figure out what is going on.
This is the `console.log` line:

```
console.log('', this, this._products, this._products[0], this._products.length);
```

but this is the result:
[image]

note that the `_products` inside the object has 3 items, but the log shows an empty array with 3 items inside, the `this._products[0]` as undefined and the `.length` as 0.

I double check where the itens are pushed into the array and everything looks fine. What seems weird for me is the fact that the console shows the array as empty and with 3 items at the same time.

Comment: This is really weird, I don't know if you noticed, but the array is undefined (you can see it on the far right), and has 0 length. Can you show how do you instanciate your array, and how do you add elements to it ?

Comment: Can you show more context around the code that prints the object?

Comment: Lazy expansion. The array is empty at the time you log it, but no longer empty at the time you click the expansion arrow.